# Drupal 7 hook_node_access not allowing "deny"?

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I created a simple module:

```
function hook_node_access($node, $op, $account)
{
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
```

It does block the access to the node, but I get this error when visiting that page:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_node_access() (line 3089 of \www\modules\node\node.module).
```

This line reads:

```
3088.    function node_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
3089.        $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
```

So basically, when I do this, $node is NOT a string, but also doesn't have a "type" value. I can only imagine that $node is a blank object when it hits this part of the code. But why?

**UPDATE**

I did a var_dump of the "node" object and I believe this is the contents:

```
int(436)
```

So, somehow the node id is getting pushed into this function, but not the node, AND the is_string function is not picking up that it's a string (because it isn't, it's an INT).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:**

What makes all of these really bad for me, is that even though I'm logged into Drupal as a user that does not have access to these nodes, they still see them if they go to /node and scroll through the pages.

Am I missing something, because surely hook_node_access should block the nodes from being seen at /node ?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing Drupal hooks, you should always replace 'hook' with your custom module name.  For example:

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account)
{
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
```

Also, you will need to clear out the Drupal cache each time you implement a new hook by going to admin/config/development/performance